# Spring-Social Dependency not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-social-facebook

I wanted to add the spring-social-facebook dependency.
It worked with the latest RELEASE 2.0.3

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I want to add the newer Version (not a release but a milestone)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.M3</version>
</dependency>
```

then maven does not find the files.
Did I forget anything?

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-facebook

For those who are interested in the whole pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>at.ennui</groupId>
    <artifactId>EnnuiBackend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>EnnuiBackend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.M3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: What `repositories` are you using in your pom.xml? Please update the question itself.

Comment: @nullpointer updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a note along with the link you've shared:

> Note: this artifact it located at Spring Milestones repository
>   (http://repo.spring.io/milestone/)

By default, maven looks for artifacts in the central repository, where you wouldn't find the 3.0.0.M3 version of your dependency as visible in [this search result.](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework.social%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-social-facebook%22)

---

Would suggest you to go through the [Introduction to repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) in maven. Accordingly modify them to include **`http://repo.spring.io/milestone/`** as the url to fetch your desired artifact.